# How do I display a DataGridView within a cell of another datagridview in C# forms app?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, datagridview, hierarchical-data

How do I display a DataGridView within a cell of another datagridview in C# forms app?

How would I have to handle Sorting & value changed if this possible?

That is the only way I can display data to make some sense.. Think of it like I have a task column and dates column. Under the dates column I have a list of things to be done. These date columns are dynamic & there might be multiple date columns

Comment: A DGV *within* another DGV?  Man, my users would kill me.  They complain enough about *un*nested DGVs. :)

Comment: Yes john.. I could also make it hierarchical (nested)
But How do I do that?

Comment: Sorry Nested isnt possible...

That is the only way I can display data to make some sense.. Think of it like I have a task column and dates column. Under the dates column I have a list of things to be done. These date columns are dynamic & there might be multiple date columns

Comment: Perhaps you want something like two DGVs.  When one DGV is selected a list of other dates would be shown in another DGV?

Comment: @galford13x - I like your Idea! This makes things simple for me, but i would prefer the user to see all the info, rather than selecting one grid and displaying it in other..

Comment: @Sachin: See my answer below as it is sort of a response to above.  Hopefully one of these .NET packages offered by different companies will provide the functionality your looking for.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like a difficult interface to use, have you considered some kind of tree control?

If you're determined to use data grid views, look at [customizing data grid view columns and cells](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7fb61s43.aspx). You need to declare custom subclasses for the column and cell behaviour that you want. I don't know if it's possible to do what you want, but that's where I would start.

Comment: 1. I am looking for edit functionality (user should be able to edit a value), and not sure how treeview is going to fit into this.

2. The link definetly gives me a starting point. I will try this approach too..

Will update status post weekend..

Answer (score 0):

This is a suggestion since what your asking I do not think is possible with the built in DGV of .NET.

Using custom controls made by professional companies that provides a DataGrid with the capability of hierarchical data.  For example a row can be expanded to show multiple entries (the multiple entries can be an entirely different table containing completely different columns even).  Here are a few options that you can check out.

[Infragistics WinGrid](http://community.infragistics.com/winforms/media/p/79129.aspx)

[Component One](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/FlexGridWinForms/)

There are a few other places/companies that make great .NET component packages that provide added features to the existing .NET components.

Comment: I would love to use one of these, but this is not a sponsored project. Cannot afford the license. :(

Answer (score 0):

http://blogs.msdn.com/markrideout/archive/2006/01/08/510700.aspx

Found a link where hierarchichal datagrid is implemented.

Now, I have to either modify the control, or settle for hierarchichal gridview!

Hope this helps someone. Will update later